How to display single scroll view for two ReorderableGridView in Flutter
I have two ReorderableGridView (from this package ReoderableGrid view ) in a page
like these
Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            if (pinnedNotes.isNotEmpty) ...[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Pinned Notes',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ReorderableGridView.count(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
                  crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
                  childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                   
                  },
                  children: pinnedNotes.map((note) {
                    return NoteCard(
                      key: ValueKey(
                          note.id), 
                      note: note,
                      deleteNote: _deleteNote,
                      togglePinnedStatus: togglePinnedStatus,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            const SizedBox(
              height: 14.0,
            ),
            if (unpinnedNotes.isNotEmpty) ...[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Text(
                  'All Notes',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ReorderableGridView.count(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
                  crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
                  childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                    
                  },
                  children: unpinnedNotes.map((note) {
                    return NoteCard(
                      key: ValueKey(
                          note.id), 
                      note: note,
                      deleteNote: _deleteNote,
                      togglePinnedStatus: togglePinnedStatus,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 14.0,
              )
            ],
          ],
        ),
      )

Which creates two scrollable list. But I want to have a single scrollable list that first displays the pinned Note and then the unpinned notes. Then I followed this answer that tells how to do it for GridView widget Link , then I had this code, but now the app freezes, doesn't interact at all and shows nothing.
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            if (pinnedNotes.isNotEmpty) ...[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Pinned Notes',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                ),
              ),
              ReorderableGridView.count(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
                crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
                childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                  
                },
                children: pinnedNotes.map((note) {
                  return NoteCard(
                    key: ValueKey(
                        note.id), 
                    note: note,
                    deleteNote: _deleteNote,
                    togglePinnedStatus: togglePinnedStatus,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
            const SizedBox(
              height: 14.0,
            ),
            if (unpinnedNotes.isNotEmpty) ...[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Text(
                  'All Notes',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ReorderableGridView.count(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
                crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
                childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                  
                },
                children: unpinnedNotes.map((note) {
                  return NoteCard(
                    key: ValueKey(
                        note.id), 
                    note: note,
                    deleteNote: _deleteNote,
                    togglePinnedStatus: togglePinnedStatus,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 14.0,
              )
            ],
          ],
        ),
      );


I had to add one property to both Reorderable.count() in second code
shrinkWrap: true

also wrap the SingleChildScrollView widget in Expanded widget
